# Set metadata recursively using s3cmd

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, s3cmd

I'm writing a shell script to sync a website tree of html files to s3.

I'd like to set the metadata of any files without an extension to text/html. Is it possible to use s3cmd -m recursively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -m modifier works recursively when syncing a folder to bucket:

```
s3cmd sync -m text/html folder/ s3://bucket
```